# Chrome Extension to display the current window's resolution

Tags: gratis, software-development, chrome

I'm looking for a Chrome Extension or setting that will display the current window's resolution in pixels. It will be used primarily in web development, and so fast and discreet is preferable. Free and open-source is also preferred if possible.

Answer (score 3):

After today, latest Chrome for Mac does not show the upper right corner dimensions area. Instead of that, one must open DevTools (as before), click on "Toggle device mode" icon and select "Responsive". Now it will show the dimensions again.

Answer (score 2):

You will see the window dimensions in the upper right corner of the client area if you open the Chrome developer tools (F12) and resize the window. No extension needed.

Comment: That's true. But the developer mode changes the inner window resolution since it needs some space for the pane

Comment: True, but there is a button in the upper right corner to undock the developer tools and make it a separate window. The dimensions still display even with the developer tools undocked.

Comment: Just today, I can't see anymore the window dimensions. I think chrome has been updated on my mac and maybe that's the case. If anyone knows anything on it...